# My .net core 3.1 server stops on azure after no use

Tags: azure, .net-core

I am struggling with problem with server on azure. I want it to work nonstop. But after no long use, when i make first request it I see in logs "Application Starting up". Do you know how to resolve it and allow server to run all the time

Comment: Do you use app service?

Answer (score 1):

If it is an App Service, you can set Always on = On, under Settings/Configuration.
You will need you App Service to run on a basic or higher Service Plan for this.